# Cannot invoke WL.Client.connect while it is already executing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

if I try to login with the wrong credentials and can't login, trying to login again with new or the same credentials i get this worklight error

> "Cannot invoke WL.Client.connect while it is already executing."

How do I stop **WL.Client.connect** if user credentials come back as invalid?

Comment: a) Is this error message specific to an environment or are you observing it across environments
b) What is your exact Worklight/MFP build version?

Comment: Figured it out, i was trying to do client.logout, whwn i should have been doing challangehandler.submitFailure ((

Comment: @Derek Hannah. If it Figured out then comment post in answer

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, i was trying to do WL.Client.logout(), when i should have been calling challangeHandler.submitFailure()